# media query for between 2 widths and over a third width

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to do the following media query but am having trouble - do I have to split it out and do 2 separate ones (repeating all the styles for each) or can they be combined in any way?

```css
.container {
  padding: rem(16px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 1550px) {
  /* want this to turn into a row in between 600 and 768 and over 1550px but the above doesn't seem to work */
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

/* have also tried 
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px),
@media only screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
  this does not work either
}

*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its look a bit weird, how can a screen have a width higher than 600 and lower than 768 but at same time be higher than 1550 ? you may think different for this question imo

Comment: @JoãoVitorDeOliveira I need the same styles to be applied for screens with either a size between 600 and 768 and for screens above 1550

Comment: So you need separated media queries for this, you must define the style for screen between 600 and 768 then create a specified style for screen higher than 1550

Comment: Thanks,someone below has shown me the answer, I just needed to miss the @media off my second attempt

Comment: Amazing, didn't know you could combine with comma separate !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine media queries with a comma.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px), screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, exactly what I needed - didn't realise you just miss off the @media from the second set of rules!

Comment: Great job, new contributor! :P

Answer (score 1):

You can completely seperate the media queries:

```css
.container {
  padding: rem(16px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
 
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1550px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width:600px) and (max-width: 768px),
(min-width: 1550px){

    .container {
        flex-direction: row;
        background: green;
        align-items: center;
     }

}
```

1. Use comma and ommit `@media` for multiple width with the same styles.
2. Make sure you have a responsive meta tag. e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`